# Is creating a Dial plan mandatory for Microsoft Exchange 2013 and Lync 2013 integration?

Tags: windows-server-2012, exchange-2013, lync-2013

I have a basic prototyping Microsoft Exchange 2013 and Lync 2013 deployment in 4 Machines:

- One Mailbox Server
- One Client Access Server
- One Lync Server (Standard Edition)
- One Active Directory (AD DS, AD CS, DNS)

I want to integrate Lync with exchange in order to have the following features:

- Lync based IM in the outlook web client
- Recieving Voice Messages in the Inbox

This [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj687983.aspx) wants me to create a Dial Plan that includes phone number configuration, in my deployment I don't have any IP phones just Lync client apps.

**Is it mandatory to create the Dial Plan and if so can I configure it with bogus settings?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my experience goes, you will need an Exchange UM dial plan if you want to receive voice messages in the inbox.  (Note that this is different from Lync dial plans).  It needs this just so you can link the voicemail policies between Lync and Exchange.

You won't need it for Lync-based IM.